# Retrieve columns from table A in comparsion to table B column values where there is no common relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

A new bird to SQL.

Table A name is EmployeeDetails which has four columns.

```
EmployeeID  FirstName,  LastName,  NativeState
        1     Frank        Dyre         FL
        2     John         Smith        AL
        3     Taylor       Cox          GA
```

Table B is CompanyDetails which has three columns

```
CompanyID   CompanyName  HeadQuatersState
 1           Steve's       FL
 2           Johnson       NY
 3           Huston        GA
```

Now in both the tables there is no same columns. But Native State and HeadQuatersStat have common states.

how can I retrieve first and lastname of an employee from employeeDetails table where the nativestate is not equals to company headquarters state.

Expected result is John Smith.

Comment: Perhaps you want to select from table A and `LEFT JOIN` to table B on the state column, then only select records where table B's state column is NULL. If you google how to select records from one table where they're not in another, you should get a whole bunch of results, though.

Comment: Hint:  `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for

```
SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName + ' ' + LastName 'Employee'
FROM EmployeeDetails
WHERE NativeState NOT IN (SELECT HeadQuartersState
                            FROM CompanyDetails)
```